# Javascript async function inside another function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call an async function inside another function. However, when I click on the network tab, it ain't creating any post request. What can be the issue here?

```
var onComplete = function() {
  // CALLING THE ASYNC FUNCTION HERE ---> { NOT WORKING }
  updateProfile()
}

async function updateProfile(){
  var dataString = {
    name: questions[0].answer,
    gender: questions[1].answer,
    dob: questions[2].answer,
    country: questions[3].answer,
    interested: questions[4].answer,
  };
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "processes/onboard.php", true);
  xhr.onload = ()=> {
    if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if(xhr.status === 200) {
        // SUCCESS
      }
    }
  }
  let formData = new FormData(form);
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(dataString));
}
```

Comment: Consider using `fetch` instead?

Comment: I assume you're calling `onComplete()` somewhere? Also, there's no need to declare that function async. You're not returning anything, and you aren't using `await` inside.

Comment: Set up some breakpoints or, if you must, some `console.log` statements to just check which lines of code are running and which ones aren't.

Comment: When I add a few lines to prevent ReferenceErrors, then call the function, it all works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/pzwksv3a/

Comment: Why so many upvotes so quickly? I don't find my question that important... Anyways... let me remove async and try again

Comment: @ChrisG Oh I got it... `let formdata`  was the culprit here... Actually this ajax request was copied from another function. Hence, this wasn't needed here as I was sending data via `dataString` and not `formdata`. Thanks for the hint. Looking at your fiddle I got the breakthrough.

Comment: @ChrisG also, the reason why I wanted to use async was because I have read somewhere that an async function waits if there is a sudden drop in the internet connection and keeps trying in the background and sends data to the server when the user is back online. I am new to Javascript. Please tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, that's not at all what `async` does. It exists so you can write synchronous code despite dealing with asynchronous processes. People used to make synchronous API requests, but they'd freeze the browser until a reply or timeout happened. Browser devs encouraged web devs to use asynchronous requests, which means callbacks. This frequently lead to the infamous "callback hell", where you'd end up with lots of nested callbacks. Along came promises, a way to write async code without nesting.

Comment: @ChrisG so you basically mean to say that if I want to use async function I should use it along with promise, right?

Comment: Kind of, it takes some time to wrap your head around it. Here's a modern version of your function: https://pastebin.com/KncFej37 Note that you could in theory return something from that function, then use `const bla = await updateProfile();` to grab that return value in a different async function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a super expert but there is a couple of recommendations we can apply

1. split the function in two to get more clean and maintainable code, which means two `async/await` blocks:

i.e

```
    function resolveRequestAfter2Seconds() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('resolved');
        }, 2000);
      });
    }
    
    async function asyncCall() {
      const result = await resolveRequestAfter2Seconds();
      console.log(result);
    }
    
    asyncCall();
```

2. Use `promise.all` to take an array of promises and return an array with your transactions once each individual call for transaction details finishes.

i.e

```
async (transactionKey, page) => {

  const api = `https://api/....`;
  const response = await axios.get(api);
  
  // create an array of promises and wait for
  // all of them to resolve before continuing

  const transactions = await Promise.all(
    response.data.map(async item => {
      const { id, transaction_id } = item;

      // get transaction details for each item in the array
      const _details = await transactionDetails(transaction_id);

      return {
        id,
        _details,
        transactionId: transaction_id,
      };
    })
  );
  return transactions;
};
```